# apply a function to some elements of a nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, apply, do.call

I wish to apply a function only to some elements of a nested list

```
l <- list()

l$a$forecast <- rnorm(3)
l$a$model <- "arima"
l$b$forecast <- rnorm(3)
l$b$model <- "prophet"
```

The desired output would be like this:
applying the sum function to the $forecast element of the list

```
fcst <- c(sum(l$a$forecast),sum(l$b$forecast))
mdl <- c(l$a$model,l$b$model)
df <- data.frame(fcst,mdl)
```

I tried something like this:

```
df <- lapply(l$forecast, function(x) sum(x))
df <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, sku = names(df)))
```

Comment: You want to sum every `forecast` element, which locate in lists called "a","b",...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    l,
    function(x) list(fcst = sum(x$forecast), model = x$model)
  )
)
```

Since you know the exact dimensions of your returned object you can use `vapply` in cases like this for a minor performance improvement:

```
vapply(
  l,
  FUN = function(x) list(fcst = sum(x$forecast), model = x$model),
  FUN.VALUE = list(fcst = numeric(1), model = character(1))
)
```

However, the resulting object can be hard to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package combined with dplyr's `bind_rows()`. This also extends to lists containing deeper nested levels.

```
rrapply::rrapply(l, condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "forecast", f = sum) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows()

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   forecast model  
#>      <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1    -1.28 arima  
#> 2     1.10 prophet
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)

l <- list(
  a = list(forecast = rnorm(3), model = "arima"),
  b = list(forecast = rnorm(3), model = "prophet")
)
```

Comment: just what the doctor ordered

Answer (score 1):

You can get the letters with the object `letters`, then using its output in a loop:

```
    n = 2 #number of lists you have
    sumfore = model = vector()
    for(i in letters[seq(1,n,1)]){
      sumfore[i] = sum(l[[i]]$forecast)
      model[i] =l[[i]]$model}
    newdf = data.frame(sumfore, model)
```